# Is there a way to implement furigana to a container that is always listening?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to make a small application for voice recognition using DeepGram, and i was able to send the mic audio on real time to deepgram and have the transcript as a response. I'm rendering that data on the html and so far so good, but i want to add furigana to the kanji's that are transcribed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Live Transcription</title>
       <style>
        #transcript-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            height: 500px;
            width: 98%;
            overflow-x: auto; /* Change to 'auto' for automatic scroll */
            background-image: url('https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/natural-japanese-recycled-paper-texture-background_118047-602.jpg?w=740');
            background-repeat: repeat;
            padding: 20px;
            line-height: 0.2; /* Adjust line height as desired */
            font-family: 'Hiragino Mincho Pro', serif;
            font-size: 18px;
            writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* Change text direction to right-to-left */
            text-align: right; /* Align text to the right */
            margin-left: auto; /* Push the container to the right side */

        }
        .transcript-line {
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h1>Transcribe Audio With Flask 2.0</h1>
        <div>
            <p id="status">Connection status will go here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="transcript-container">
        </div>
         <script>
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
            if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm'))
                return alert('Browser not supported')
             const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                mimeType: 'audio/webm',
            })
             const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5555/listen')
             socket.onopen = () => {
                document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'Connected'
                mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', async (event) => {
                    if (event.data.size > 0 && socket.readyState == 1) {
                        socket.send(event.data)
                    }
            })
            mediaRecorder.start(250)
            }
             socket.onmessage = (message) => {
                const received = message.data
                if (received) {
                    const transcriptContainer = document.querySelector('#transcript-container')
                    const transcriptLine = document.createElement('p')
                    transcriptLine.className = 'transcript-line'
                    transcriptLine.textContent = message.data
                    transcriptContainer.appendChild(transcriptLine)
                }
            }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the simple html index page that i have, so u can see how im recieving the deepgrams transcript and showing it on the container... I'm using flask and python to run it.

I've tried libraries but some are depricated, and im not sure how to implement a javascript furigana library, nor how to implement it correctly. Is there anyone who knows how to solve this matter?